# Confirming my solution to the expansion of $z/(z-1)(z+3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I would just like a confirmation of my work for the following problem.

> Represent the function $$ \frac{z}{(z-1)(z+3)} $$ as a Laurent Series around $z=0$ when $1<|z|<3$.

Using partial fraction decomposition to simplify the problem a bit, 
$$ \frac{1}{(z-1)(z+3)} = \frac{1}{4(z-1)} - \frac{1}{4(z+3)} \\ \Rightarrow  \frac{z}{(z-1)(z+3)} = \frac{z}{4(z-1)} - \frac{z}{4(z+3)}$$

Tackling each fraction seperatly, 
$$ \frac{1}{z-1} = \frac{1}{z}\cdot \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}} = \frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n-1}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{-n} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{z}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{z-1} = \frac{z}{4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{-n} 
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{-(n-1)}}{4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-n}}{4} \\ $$

$$ \frac{1}{3+z} = \frac{1}{3z} \cdot \frac{1}{1-(-3z)^{-1}} = \frac{1}{3z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{-n}}{3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n z^{-n-1}}{9} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} z^{-n}}{9} \\ \Rightarrow \frac{z}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{3+z} = \frac{z}{4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} z^{-n}}{9} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} z^{-(n-1)}}{36} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} z^{-n}}{36} \\ $$

Now adding them back together,
$$ \frac{z}{(z-1)(z+3)} = \frac{z}{4(z-1)} - \frac{z}{4(z+3)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-n}}{4} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} z^{-n}}{36} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(9-(-1)^n)}{36} z^{-n} $$

Therefore, 
$$ \frac{z}{(z-1)(z+3)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(9-(-1)^n)}{36} z^{-n} \ \
 \ (1<|z|<3) $$

Does everything look correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Your expansion of $\frac1{3+z}$ does not hold (already the first transformation is wrong).

Comment: Hmm, since your result has only non-positive powers of $z$, it ought to converge near infinity, rather than in an annulus.

Comment: @Did could you elaborate a bit? Why is it wrong?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, if a Laurent series for $f$ centred at $z_{0}$ contains infinitely many negative powers of $z-z_{0}$, then $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_{0}$ - that isn't the case for your function.

Comment: Because $$ \frac{1}{3+z} $$ is not at all $$ \frac{1}{3z} \cdot \frac{1}{1-(-3z)^{-1}}$$ (Why couldn't you check this yourself, one wonders.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

\begin{align*}
 f(z)&=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+3)}\\
 &=\frac{1}{4(z-1)}+\frac{3}{4(z+3)}\\
\end{align*}
 has two simple poles at $z=1$ and $z=-3$.

> Since we want to find a Laurent expansion with center $0$, we look at the poles $1$ and $-3$ and see they determine *three* regions.
>
> \begin{align*}
>  |z|<1,\qquad\quad
> 1<|z|<3,\qquad\quad
>  3<|z|
>  \end{align*}
>
> - The first region $ |z|<1$ is a disc with center $0$, radius $1$ and the pole $1$ at the boundary of the disc. In the *interior* of this disc all two fractions with poles $1$ and $-3$  admit a representation as *power series* at $z=0$.
> - The second region $1<|z|<3$ is the annulus with center $0$, inner radius $1$ and outer radius $3$. Here we have a representation of the fraction with the pole at $1$ as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=0$, while the fraction with pole at $-3$ admits a representation as power series.
> - The third region $|z|>3$ containing all points outside the disc with center $0$ and radius $3$ admits for all fractions a representation as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=0$.

A power series expansion of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{a}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}(-z)^n
\end{align*}
The principal part of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{z}}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{(-z)^n}
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{(-z)^{n+1}}\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n-1}}{(-z)^n}
\end{align*}

> We can now obtain the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ for all three regions. Here we have to consider
>
> - *Region 2:* $1<|z|<3$
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\frac{1}{4(z-1)}+\frac{3}{4(z+3)}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(-z)^n}+\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}(-z)^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{z^n}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(- \frac{1}{3}\right)^nz^n\\
> \end{align*}
>
> The Laurent expansion for the other regions can be calculated similarly.

Comment: Why is it $(-1)^{n-1}$?

Comment: @gbox: The principal part of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a^{n-1}}{(-z)^n}$ evaluated at $a=-1$.

Comment: @Did: Thanks for your support. :-)